# Build Fail after Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Gradle build failed after android studio update. It typically does after updates, but this time invalidating caches and restarting didn't help. It's not giving me much, just says 'myprojectname' failed in build log. It shows my main activity in red in manifest as an unresolved class, also google imports are unresolved.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is happening with me also

Comment: Same situation here, I spent almost 12 hours until now, trying just to build a brand new basic project without success until now. Very very frustrating....

I suspect libraries incompatibilities with selected AGP and gradle versions, without knowing which version matches to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you, try (tab)Build/Rebuild Project. It created a gradle sync error message on the bottom, suggesting upgrading,and clicking this eventually leads you to prompts for downloading and resyncing upgraded gradles (took about half an hour). Would have been nice to have gotten a prompt from the start with the failed after studio upgrade build attempt.